# C# Generics type inference for comman

Tags: c#, .net, easynetq

I have to use specific API which I don't have control over:

```
TResponse Request<TRequest, TResponse>(TRequest request) 
    where TRequest : class 
    where TResponse : class;
```

This is an RPC wrapper for RabbitMq from EasyNetQ library

I would like to have some way to define TRequest to TResponse relation, so that I don't have to manually match them every call like this :

```
this._client.Request<CancelPaymentByMerchantRequest, CancelPaymentByMerchantResponse>(request);
```

The solution I come up with is :

```
public interface ICommand<TRequest, TResponse> { }

public class StartCommand : ICommand<StartCommand, StartResponse>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Args { get; set; }
}

public class StartResponse
{
    public bool Success { get; set; }

    public string Error { get; set; }
}
```

And a consumer for it :

```
 public TResponse Send<TRequest, TResponse>(ICommand<TRequest, TResponse> payload)
            where TRequest : class
            where TResponse : class
        {
            var result = client.Request<TRequest, TResponse>((TRequest)payload);
            return result;
        }
```

Is it possible to get rid of TRequest type on ICommand marker interface?

I am also worried about extra costs related to having marker interface, and then direct cast from it in the actual library call.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The simplest way to achieve this would just be to add an abstraction around `Send` once per `TRequest` type:

```
public SpecificResponse Send(SpecificRequest payload)
{
    return Send<SpecificRequest, SpecificResponse>(payload);
}
```

You'll have to define an overload for `Send` per `TRequest, TResponse` pair but then the rest of your application can use these "strongly-typed" versions to avoid having to restate the relationship everywhere.

How you orchestrate this is up to you but I'd prefer an interface/class per request/response type that acts as an intermediary to the generic layer (alternatively one big interface with a bunch of contracts on it would work just as well).